when validate item did not work in form 6i
See my simple code in form 6i for checking the barcode scanning.
I am trying to check when textbox length is ten then show a message but it did not work when the validate item triggers:
if  Length (:fgdetail.refstr) = 10  then 
    message('testing date');
    message('testing data');
end if;

Please give me an idea.

What happens if you include ELSE (so that a different message is displayed)? Do you see it (because length isn't 10)?

The cursor did not advance to the next item when the barcode was scanned and the length was equal to 10. I utilized an else statement with an if condition. You can review my code for more details.        ///   if  Length(:fgdetail.refstr) >=  10  then
message('tessting');
message('tessting ');
go_item(':fgdetail.REFNUM');
else
message('---------------------');
message('----------------');
end if;

The Validate the Item process wouldn't happen when data was entered into a field, so the when-validate-item trigger won't fire.  The cursor needs to leave the field for the process and trigger to fire.  Or try to save the record while the cursor is still in the field.

Dear Sir,
I would like to inquire about how to enable the automatic movement of the cursor to the next item when a barcode is scanned or when any other trigger is used to perform this task. Thank you.

@MuhammadFahimAamir  Well, that's a completely different question, and would require a new post.  And since I have no experience using barcode scanners with Oracle forms, somebody else will have to provide an answer.
